# AngularJs ng-init with value from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a controller, service and ng-select.

controller:

```
$scope.dicts = shareService.dict.obj;
```

service:

```
 var dict = {
    "obj": {
        "companyCode" : []
    }
}
```

and html:

```
<select ng-model="companyCode" ng-options="company.value as company.name for company in dicts['companyCode'] track by company.value">
```

My problem: when the site loads, the first value in select is empty. Yeah "companyCode" is empty, but it's generated in init(). And it shows the company.name (after selecting one the blank field disappers), but as I said, I need a default value. No idea how. And yes it is needed to be done this way in service.

ok, main problem is that when the ng-init is called, the companyCode array is empty, after that it's filled with actual values. Is there anyway to run ng-init after that?

Comment: you need the default value?

Comment: Add some more code related to controller and service

Comment: yup, first value from "companyCode" for example